# where data will be stored when we create hive external table without location properties

Tags: hive, hiveql

I created external table without any location. Now where the data will be stored even when we dropped table.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE forest(
  animal string,
  food string)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create external table with out location , the data will be stored in the hive default location.
Usually
 `/apps/hive/warehouse/<database_name>.db/<table_name>`.

If you create the table in test database , your hive location will be

```
/apps/hive/warehouse/test.db/forest
```

If you drop the table , you can find the data in this location.
Use the command `show create table forest;` which will give you the details of the location, if you haven't dropped it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify location for the external table, it will be stored under default hive warehouse location.

See example below.

```
hive> USE ramesh;
OK
Time taken: 0.013 seconds
hive> CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test 
    >  (col1 BIGINT, col2 STRING)
    > ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
    > FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    > STORED AS TEXTFILE;
OK
Time taken: 0.056 seconds
hive> SHOW CREATE TABLE test;
OK
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`(
  `col1` bigint, 
  `col2` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'field.delim'=',', 
  'serialization.format'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
**LOCATION
  'hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/ramesh.db/test'**
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'COLUMN_STATS_ACCURATE'='false', 
  'numFiles'='0', 
  'numRows'='-1', 
  'rawDataSize'='-1', 
  'totalSize'='0', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1510257748')
Time taken: 0.044 seconds, Fetched: 21 row(s)
```